# Does the new Instagram Graph API include a location element for media item?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am reviewing the new Instagram Graph API and looking for a location element for the media item endpoint.

What I'm looking to achieve is a way to search a location for images posted that have locations tagged in that area or a location.

I'm looking at the media item endpoint in their reference page at:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/

The Instagram API documentation doesn't seem to include this at present. Does anyone know if the media item will include a location element? e.g. by place name or lat/long.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Instagram Graph API which is from facebook api - is only for those instagram accounts which are converted to business account. In other words linked to fb business pages.

That API gives only owned data and the moderation for comments and deep insights on account posts.

The is Instagram api for your use case which is open for all accounts. You would want something like this: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/locations/

This gives all the recent media in reverse chronological based on a location id.

But there is a caveat: It needs `public_content` oauth scope; which Instagram has stopped issuing for new auth apps. So, if you don't have that enabled already, probably you won't be able to get that access authorised. Plus, this api is scheduled to be deprecated in 2020.

Comment: Hi @enator - thanks for your reply. We were fortunate enough to have access granted for our app to public_content oauth scope a couple of years back and we've been using the /locations endpoint for a while now. Our app creates a geo-fenced query to identify all Facebook location ID's within a set lat/long radius, then call all Instagram media items tagged in that location - works well. From what you say - if the public_content and /locations endpoint remain till 2020 we should still be able to query the feed by this method until then - is that your thoughts? thanks heaps

Comment: The complete API is scheduled to be deprecated in 2020. but public_content is end of 2018. here are the official dates: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/01/30/instagram-graph-api-updates/

hope it helps

Comment: Hey @AndrewTweedie I am trying to fetch the Instagram location-tagged posts using an Instagram user access token. The current API documentation is pretty messy, is your app still working fine? Any thoughts on how to do that in Nov 2021?